# Is it possible to intercept an http://example.com/callback redirect in a intentFilter?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, intentfilter

I'm trying to use an Intent-Filter to capture when a browser redirected to a page confirming the authorization process (final url for test is "http://shapp.sytes.net:8080/callback/loginsuccessful?client_id=...".

But I'm able to open the native browser from within app, it goes to auth page, gets redirected to link above, but my intent-filter does not intercept the redirect.

Is it possible to do it and I'm missing something?

Tried some variations of the code bellow. And also tried to start the activity via adb. 
Gettin this error: Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://shapp.sytes.net:2080/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.companyname.oauthnativeflow }

```
[Activity(Label = "CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity", NoHistory = true, 
LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "http"},
    DataHosts = new [] { "shapp.sytes.net:2080"},
    //DataPath = "/Callback",
    DataPathPrefix ="/callback")]
public class CustomUrlSchemeInterceptorActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Convert Android.Net.Url to Uri
        var uri = new Uri(Intent.Data.ToString());

        // Load redirectUrl page
        AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri);

        Finish();
    }
}
```

A break-point in the OnCreate method is never activated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your Intent-filter looks fine, is the *default* app for `http` scheme set a single app? Otherwise since you are using an existing registered scheme and not a custom schema that is unique to just your app, the user should be prompted which app to use to open it.

Comment: @SushiHangover - Once I was prompted to select between the browser and my app. But only  for the initial page, not the redirect for the final page. But how can I check if the default is set to single app? this is in my code or in the device? Because if it is for the device, or if the user will always be prompted to select, probably it won't work well. Although, this gave me an different Idea.

Comment: Look in Settings/App/Defaults (it is a device level feature, not an app one), typically you would not use http/https as the scheme, but a custom one (i.e. the Android package name of your app) in order to perform deep linking

Comment: Took an alternative solution. Could not use a MyApp: as scheme because facebook accepts only https redirects. So I went to server. After the last redirect from face to server, I made a button with a redirect to MyApp: and my IntentFilter worked.